# What's the name of this whiskey glass style?

Tags: whiskey, glassware

I accidentally broke a vintage whiskey glass that I got from a friend's father when he passed away. I've been looking for a replacement in a similar style, but haven't been able to find anything suitable. The bottom of the glass was cut in a particular way, similar to what's found in [this link](https://chairish-prod.freetls.fastly.net/image/product/sized/ff7d9f15-23f9-43ea-896e-9e3aa6f4b9f4/vintage-italian-crystal-lowballwhiskey-glasses-set-of-7-0283?aspect=fit&width=1600&height=1600), though not quite the same. What I had was much more intricate, and there were four major protrusions from the bottom.

Does anyone have an idea of what this bottom cut style is called? Most whiskey glasses I find when I search online just have a round bottom.

EDIT: For some extra info, the etchings on the side of the glass I had were similar to those found in [this ebay listing](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/234522460714?hash=item369aa0c22a:g:xo4AAOSw3r1iY%7E1R&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4GshO219Y7eM1hPd%2B8eMGfUjG1s3NSdkwYn%2BVmoQDTXXGZ5OoA27MpCB%2B9oQ6qqkSkhJlPwBOYYAJk6HYb2FDoPRtuyCU5FniqlMcrIi0N4blihq7Cv%2BHbkQAbG%2BPWzqzEsCmHGOFF3h1z3fKevsVzgTuzvXkHXQsm%2B%2B4Qmf9XygYsZ%2FJ8QyxGZUnruTgL%2F3jwOwQmr35%2FHiqa25yT15iO%2FIaeEZ0Stui%2BZgegCQcskiqmMBRQgHNI1sEaBoxB9ILjQP5Q6gfa1o0zRbVYCgtuk5Ky7xlgubKi7tzBbcOFk4%7Ctkp%3ABFBMjqTU8rNh). If anyone has information on who made these glasses or what kind of etchings they are, this may help.

Comment: I think if you search for crystal glass tumblers, eventually, you could stumble upon one of these. Also try to search local thrift shops for that, then you might be lucky to also not pay high prices

Comment: @Horsty thanks! Yeah I eventually learned that the pattern is called "pinwheel", so I was able to find a lot of those. However, finding that cut base is nearly impossible and I don't think there is any kind of standard terminology for that. One link calls it "cathedral style" but that's about it. Anyways yes, onto the thrift/antique stores!